# Swift Realm : How read metadata which it saved with users in realm studio?

Tags: realm, swift4, realm-mobile-platform

I want to add some info in Metadata for realm user such as 
Key "username"
Value "any"

How read this Metadata using swift?

I tried to use

```
if let user=SyncUser.current{
    let username = user.value(forKey: "username") as? String ?? ""
 }
```

This case an error:

> '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key username.'

How to solve this issue or any suggestion?